# Any one Input required textarea or Checkbox in HTML form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Required One Input - textarea or checkbox(atleast one) or both

```
<textarea class="form-control" style="width: 500px; height: 100px;" name="xyz" value="tvs" rows="4" cols="80" maxlength="20000"></textarea><br>
```

Or

Select atleast one checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="bus"> I have a bus<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="truck"> I have a truck<br>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want my form to input textarea or select checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use JQuery to check that at least one has been filled in.

```
function validate_form() {
  var valid = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0 || $('textarea#mytextarea').val() == "";
  if(valid) {
    alert ( "You need to select something" );
  }
```

Comment: You should probably remove that semicolon in line 3. Also, you could just do straight `var valid = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0 || $('textarea#mytextarea').val() == "";` and do `if(valid)` and simply alert the message and skip `valid = false;`.

Comment: Much cleaner, thanks @Jonast92

Answer (score 0):

Some jQuery will do the trick, use the Validation Plugin which will make this a lot easier http://jqueryvalidation.org/

then use a rule callback:

```
rules: {
textarea: {
    required: function(element) {
        return $("#textarea").is(':empty');
    }
},
checkboxes: {
    required: function(element) {
        return $(".checkboxes:checkbox:checked").length > 0);
    }
}
}
```

you will need to add classes to the the checkbox inputs as

```
class="{checkboxes: true}"
```

Or whatever you decide to make that class. Also you should adapt the class to be less generic.

Comment: This jquery is only for checkbox  ,I want my form to input textarea or select checkbox, any one or both?

Comment: In my form i want - if i give input to textarea than it is not compulsory to select checkbox and vice-versa

Comment: I was editing it, I just realized that after submitting ;)

Comment: please send me the link to validation plugin